# SVN DB Error - Fatal error, run database recovery

Tags: linux, debian, svn

When I tried to access svn repo from the browser I'm getting the below error in the syslog. Can I know how do i repair it using any svn tools.

```
  Error string not specified yet: Berkeley DB error while opening environment for filesystem / var/svn/1761/db:\nDB_RUNRECOVERY: Fatal error, run database recovery
```

Thanks & Regards
Caterpillar

Answer (score 2):

Use "svn-admin recover" on the repository, as the svn user. First get sure that there isn't any other system error like a disk drive error, filesystem corruption, filesystem full.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I checked whatever you said, I have a weekly backup for all the svn repos. I checked this repo's log file. it is as below error.

svn: Berkeley DB error while opening environment for filesystem /var/svn2/1761/db:
DB_RUNRECOVERY: Fatal error, run database recovery
svn: bdb: PANIC: fatal region error detected; run recovery

svn: Berkeley DB error while opening environment for filesystem /var/svn2/1761/db:
DB_RUNRECOVERY: Fatal error, run database recovery
svn: bdb: PANIC: fatal region error detected; run recovery

Comment: Did you try to run the "svn-admin recovery /path/to/repo" ?

Comment: I tried it, It showed as below.
Repository lock acquired.
Please wait; recovering the repository may take some time...

Recovery completed.
The latest repos revision is 684.

Even after that the issues did not resolve. Anyhow I have restored from backup, But everytime restoration is not the solution. I have faced the same issue twice in a week with another repo. :(

Comment: Well, hard to know what's wrong. What's the software and hardware configuration? (linux distro, memory, hard disk drive). I'd look for a software update first, than for some hardware error. Run memtest86+ and check your disk drives for defects (run badblocks).